# Not Found: /media/ on form submit

Tags: python, django

I have a form with a `ImageField()` in it I've already set the media URL and directory and such in setting.py and url.py and on submit everything works perfectly, but suddenly now every time I try submit my form it fails and says in  python terminal :

> [17/Feb/2018 14:40:08] "POST /form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37885
>
> Not Found: /media/

I didn't modify either setting.py or the url.py (see code below):

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

model.py

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name (as in NRIC)")
    def upload_photo_dir(self, filename):
        path = 'hiring/employees/photo/{}'.format(filename)
        return path

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo_dir)
```

view.py

```
def application_form_view(request):
    form = Model_AForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        inst = form.save(commit=False)
        inst.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form.html', context=context)
```

html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="application_form" name="application_form">
<label>name :</label>
{{ form.name}}
<label>Photo:</label>
{{ form.photo }}
</form>
```

Comment: Did you create media folder in your project?

Comment: yes I did, it works before, but I created a few more folder inside my media but it shouldn't mess the directory

Answer (score 0):

Change below constants in Settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Ensure that `DEBUG` is `True` if you running on port and not at server. Keep False at web server (nginix,apache etc).

Verify below statements in urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

As you have mentioned `hiring/employees/photo/` path in your model file field this must be present in your root folder.

```
`hiring/employees/photo/` #Must be created at root of your project with permissions of 755.
```

And yes as denis said, `media` folder is also need to be there at root. with this path.

Comment: base_dir not a root, it's base django project dir, there root urls.py config and so on

Comment: HI, its still not working, i should note that i have no problem saving this from admin, but here its not

Comment: Are you using niginx or running at port? like 8000 etc? Please check my edit, you need to add `if settings.DEBUG:` in urls.py file.

Comment: im running at port, from cmd

Comment: Please check the edit  you need to add `if settings.DEBUG:` in urls.py file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165321/discussion-between-anup-yadav-and-m-izzat).

Comment: Is your `settings.DEBUG` is False? make that `True` at server you need to make False as you mostly run on server instead of port

Comment: my apologies, my office block the chat page, i think i dent set my settings.DEBUG to True, but its weird, initialy i dont set it, but its saving

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found this useful. Thanks